# Splitting TCHAR into bidimensional vector

Tags: c++, winapi

I wanna split a TCHAR message like the given example:

```
TCHAR [1000] = "[X][X]   [X][X][X]   [X][P][-]..."
```

into a bidimensional vector, to look like this:

[image]

```
void Comunnication::receiveMessage(tstring msg){

    TCHAR gameMessage[1000];
    vector<vector<tstring>> gameMap;

    BOOL isSucceed = ReadFile(serverUpdatePipe, gameMessage, sizeof(gameMessage), &bytesRead, NULL);

    gameMessage[bytesRead / sizeof(TCHAR)] = '\0';

    if (!isSucceed || !bytesRead){
        break;
    }

    //Wrong 
    for (DWORD i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        vector<tstring> line;
        for (DWORD j = 0; j < 15; j++)
        {
            // get 3 charaters of each time
        }
        communication.getMap().push_back(line);
    }

}
```

The problem here is that i don't know exactly how to get 3 characters (each block of the map) and save it on the bidimensional vector.

Comment: You can use `getchar` which gets one character every time. Just call it three times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of these following function:

- `std::istream::get`

You can read about this function in [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/),`istream& get (char* s, streamsize n);`.

Example:

```
char *s;
cin.get(s, 4);
cout << s << endl;
```

and output:

```
string test
str
```

- `std::istream::read`

Or you can use this function, `istream& read (char* s, streamsize n);`. Description in [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/). 
If use this function, you must define size of line is 3 before.

Example:

```
char s[3];
cin.read(s, 3);
cout << s << endl;
```

and output:

```
string test
str
```